# How to pass variables from one object in one scene to another object in another scene in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to pass variables from one object in one scene to another object in another scene? If so, I need to pass unityNameSelected global variable from first script(which is listed bellow) attached in an object in scene 2 to the second script attached to another object in the scene 1. Thanks for any help.

```
{

        while ( reader.Read() ) 
        {
            if ( reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element ) 
            {
                if ( reader.HasAttributes ) 
                {
                    if ( reader.GetAttribute("UnityName") != null ) 
                    {
                        unityName = reader.GetAttribute("UnityName");
                        if(!values.Contains(unityName))
                        {
                   values.Add(unityName);
                   DontDestroyOnLoad(GameObject.Find("unityName")); 


                         unityNameSelected = unityName;
                    //string[]  unityNameSelected3 = {unityName};
                    //   unityNameSelected =unityNameSelected3;
                           print(unityNameSelected.ToString());

          }
                   }
                            }
                    }
                }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you already know how to prevent the object from being destroyed by unity (`DontDestroyOnLoad`). So all you now need to do is store it in some place where it will still be accessible after the next level has loaded. A simple way to do this is a static variable:

```
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameObject unityNameSelected;
}
```